# What features of Squid 3 would allow the blocking of all traffic and then just adding servers to a whitelist that are allowed through?

Tags: squid, http-proxy, dansguardian, ssl-bump

I just installed [Gate Sentry](https://github.com/fifthsegment/GateSentry) on a Raspberrry PI 3, and I'm able to block https facebook;  provided I set the browser to use the proxy on port 8080 and the certificate.  It gives me a nice content blocked page after that.

I looked at the configuration and it is using the Dansguardian proxy on port 8080 which then forwards to Squid 3 on port 3127, and if all goes well it forwards to the internet connection on my router.

But I'd like to make this more exclusive, and make a list of servers only to which one is allowed to visit.

So what do I need to read up on in Dansguardian, or Squid3 to black list all sites / servers other than the ones the user is allowed to access?  I'd like to setup an deny / allow rule rather than an allow / deny.

This is for purposes of keeping a kid focused on their homework and keeping them off of the social media, during times when it is required for them to focus on such things.

Comment: will it work?... proxies, tor, free vpns in ios

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Will what work?

Comment: blocking social media and kids...have a look at setting up a transparent proxy, it might help too.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Yeah I'm looking into that too, but this is the very early stages of things...

Comment: I would venture say that if you want a whitelist only, you do not need dansguardian.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I only have it on there because it came with Gate Sentry.  I'm pretty new at this...I've wanted to do this for years, but it's only recently that I've found a ready made solution for it.

Comment: I understand your point of view now. Doing it with squid : http://www.webdnstools.com/articles/squid-proxy-whitelist

Comment: Dansguardian is no longer maintained. You should probably be using e2guardian instead. Please [edit] your question so that it doesn't mention Dansguardian, then let me know in a comment that you've done so.